# If a request is made through the ingress for intra-cluster communication, does K8s route using private IPs?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Service A in a K8s cluster that needs to communicate with Service B via a http request.
Unfortunately, we cannot do a call like `curl http://serviceb.namespace.svc.cluster.local` because we are using Kong as our API gateway, and to take advantage of its auth plugins we need to make requests through the ingress. Thus, we need to make a call like `curl https://serviceb.somedomain.com`.

I'm trying to understand if there's a downside to this approach. For example, does this cause the request to get routed to the outside world and then back into the cluster, thus causing increased latency? Or is K8s somehow clever enough to route entirely within the vpc of the cluster?

Comment: The request would be routed to the internet in this case.

Comment: Is the Kong running in k8s? Can you do `curl http://kong.namespace.svc.cluster.local` ?

Comment: @Matt yes Kong is running in K8s in the default namespace. I tried your curl command from another pod running in the cluster and it didn't work, but I modified it to the following and it worked: `curl http://kong-kong-proxy.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: Do you consider it solved then? If so, would you mind adding answer to this question in answers section?